# What is wrong with this code? why the List does not identify?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

what is wrong with this code?

```
bool claimExists;
        string currentClaimControlNo = "700209308399870";
        List<string> claimControlNo = new List<string>();
        claimControlNo.Add("700209308399870");

        if (claimControlNo.Contains(currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14)))
            claimExists = true;
        else
            claimExists = false;
```

Why the claimControlNo above is coming into false?
Since I know the value exists, how can i tune the code?

Comment: The confusion lies in the fact that `Substring(int,int)` is `Substring(offset,length)`, not `Substring(startIndex,stopIndex)`

Comment: what you want to achieve is not clear. You are not looking for the exact string or you would not be using substring. I guess @AnnL. has pointed your goal. Then, will it be equals, contains, startswith ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reporting false because you aren't asking whether the list contains the `currentClaimControlNo`, you're asking whether it contains a string that is the first fourteen characters of the fifteen-character string `currentClaimControlNo`.

Try this instead:

```
 claimExists = claimControlNo.Any(ccn => ccn.StartsWith(currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0,14)));
```

Comment: I edited my answer 2 minutes before you posted.  Did you get the later version (using String.StartsWith)?

Answer (score 2):

Your count is wrong. There are 15 characters. Your substring is cutting off the last 0 which fails the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Because contains on a list looks for the whole item, not a substring:

```
currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14)
"70020930839987"
```

Is not the same as

```
 700209308399870
```

You're missing a digit, hence why your list search is failing.

I think you are trying to find something in the list that contains that substring.  Don't use the lists contain method.  If you are trying to find something in the list that has the subset do this

```
claimExists = claimControlNo.Any(item => item.Contains(currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14)))
```

This goes through each item in `claimControlNo` and each item can then check if it contains the substring.

Why do it this way? The `Contains` method on a string

> Returns a value indicating whether the specified System.String object occurs within this string.

Which is what you want.

`Contains` on a list, however

> Determines whether an element is in the System.Collections.Generic.List.

They aren't the same, hence your confusion

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need this explaining?

You are calling `Substring` for 14 characters when the string is of length 15. Then you are checking if your list (which only has one item of length 15) contains an item of length 14. It doesn;t event need to check the value, the length is enough to determine it is not a match.

The solution of course is to not do the `Substring`, it makes not sense.

Which would look like this:

```
if (claimControlNo.Contains(currentClaimControlNo))
    claimExists = true;
else
    claimExists = false;
```

---

Then again, perhaps you know you are trimming the search, and are in fact looking for anything that has a partial match within the list?

If this is the case, then you can simply loop the list and do a `Contains` on each item. Something like this:

```
bool claimExists = false;
string searchString = currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14);
foreach(var s in claimControlNo)
{
   if(s.Contains(searchString))
   {
      claimExists = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

Or use some slightly complex (certainly more complex then I can remember off the top of my head) LINQ query. Quick guess (it's probably right to be fair, I am pretty freaking awesome):

```
bool claimExists = claimControlNo.Any(x => x.Contains(searchString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're shaving off the last digit in your substring.

if you change the line

```
if (claimControlNo.Contains(currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14)))
```

to

```
if (claimControlNo.Contains(currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 15)))
```

it works.

Comment: I knew better than to think I could answer this in time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check it:

```
// str will be equal to 70020930839987
var str = currentClaimControlNo.Substring(0, 14);

List<string> claimControlNo = new List<string>();
claimControlNo.Add("700209308399870");
```

The value str isn't contained in the list.